# How to combine multiple rows (one column) into One row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL server 2017 and I have a scenario where I want to combine multiple rows of data into one row. Please see the below screenshot and let me know if that is possible. Thank you. Apologies if anything is missing.

Please let me know the query on how to achieve this

[image: Please see the below pic for the expected output I would like to see]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server has supported `string_agg()` since 2017:

```
select employeeid, lastname,
       string_agg(projectname, ',') within group (order by projectname) as projectnames
from t
group by employeeid, lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT 
       E.Employeeid,
       E.Lastname,
       [Projects] =(( SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + [Project Name] 
              FROM yourTable AS T
              WHERE T.Employeeid = E.Employeeid
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
    FROM yourTable AS E
    GROUP E.Employeeid,
       E.Lastname
    ORDER BY E.Employeeid
```